# Build runnable jar google Dataflow project with Gradle

Tags: gradle, executable-jar, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to build a runnable jar from Google Dataflow project with Gradle.
I just added this code in `build.gradle` to export jar:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Deepmind Jar File',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'MyMainClass'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

I had tried with sample main class to export jar and it works fine.
But when I applied main class that contains google dataflow pipeline, after I run the jar file, I got an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to return a default Coder for Transform: UsersNormalize/RemoveDuplication: usersDailyCollection/Format: usersDailyNormalize/ParMultiDo(Anonymous).out0 [PCollection]. Correct one of the following root causes:
  No Coder has been manually specified;  you may do so using .setCoder().
  Inferring a Coder from the CoderRegistry failed: Unable to provide a Coder for com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow.
  Building a Coder using a registered CoderProvider failed.
  See suppressed exceptions for detailed failures.
  Using the default output Coder from the producing PTransform failed: Unable to provide a Coder for com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow.
  Building a Coder using a registered CoderProvider failed.
  See suppressed exceptions for detailed failures.
```

Can anybody help to solve this problem or suggest how to create a runnable jar for google dataflow project?

Comment: Thanks for format my question @Frogatto

Answer (score 0):

We simply use `distTar` (which will contain your JAR file):

```
distTar {
 compression = Compression.GZIP
 mainClassName = '<main-class>'
 applicationName = '<app-name>'
 jar.baseName = applicationName
 dependsOn('test')
}
```

Comment: Thanks Graham Polley, I will try this. But now I had fixed my issue by add buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath "eu.appsatori:gradle-fatjar-plugin:0.3"
  }
}